# What does "to have something built" mean?

Tags: meaning

> This case is waiting to have pages built

It's a UI sentence, and what does "to have pages built"? Does it mean that "this case is waiting for the pages to be built"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably. All you can really be sure of is that the info you wanted isn't available right now. Someone who knows the application really well may be able to tell you what it actually means, but on the face of it your expansion means pretty much the same as I would *assume* was meant origially.